# Controversy about the death of Muhammad(SAW)

Tags: prophet-muhammad, death

How did Muhammad SAW actually died?There is so much controversy about how he died.Some say,he died a natural death.some say,he was posioned.Sometimes some people say he was killed by Aisha RA and Hafsa RA (Nauzubullah)

Comment: There is no controversy. Unless you are listening to conspiracy theories. In that case, there is controversy in everything.

Answer (score 1):

Our beloved Prophet Mohammad (may Allah’s peace and blessings be upon him)died by a natural death, after 12-14 days getting sickness.He had severe headaches, high fever and pain.  Reports indicate that the pain was caused by poisoned lamb tasted three years earlier during the Battle of Khaybar.   [Muhibb al-Tabari, Khulasa Siyar Sayyid al-Bashar]

There are several hadith (translations) about the effects of the poisoning on the Prophet Mohammed (SAS) from the time he tasted the meat until his death, with the following the most well-known and reliable verse: Narrated `Aisha: “The Prophet (SAS) in his ailment in which he died, used to say, ‘O ‘Aisha! I still feel the pain caused by the food I ate at Khaibar, and at this time, I feel as if my aorta is being cut from that poison’.” Sahih al-Bukhairi Hadith 4428 Book 64, Hadith 450
But according to my knowledge all these controversies results that he died his natural death.